# Write HTML to string

Tags: c#, html

I have code like this. Is there a way to make it easier to write and maintain?
Using C# .NET 3.5.

```
string header(string title)
{
    StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
    s.WriteLine("{0}","<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">");
    s.WriteLine("{0}", "<html>");
    s.WriteLine("<title>{0}</title>", title);
    s.WriteLine("{0}","<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\">");
    s.WriteLine("{0}", "</head>");
    s.WriteLine("{0}", "<body>");
    s.WriteLine("{0}", "");
}
```

I could also just write:

```
s.WriteLine("{0}", @"blah blah

many
new
lines
blah UHY#$&_#$_*@Y KSDSD<>\t\t\t\t\t\tt\t\t\\\t\t\t\t\\\h\th'\h't\th
hi
done");
```

It will work, but I need to replace all `"` with `""`.

Comment: It's good that you relize this is a bad way to make an html file using a program.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937201 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897226 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346449

Comment: why use the `{0}` at all? Except for the title, you don't need it. You can just put your string as the first argument and don't use a second argument.

Answer (score 91):

You're probably better off using an [`HtmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) or an [`XMLWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlWriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than a plain `StringWriter`. They will take care of escaping for you, as well as making sure the document is well-formed.

[This page](http://dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter) shows the basics of using the `HtmlTextWriter` class, the gist of which being:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, classValue);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div); // Begin #1

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, urlValue);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A); // Begin #2

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, imageValue);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "60");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Height, "60");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Alt, "");

    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img); // Begin #3
    writer.RenderEndTag(); // End #3

    writer.Write(word);

    writer.RenderEndTag(); // End #2
    writer.RenderEndTag(); // End #1
}
// Return the result.
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: Reference System.Web

Answer (score 25):

When I deal with this problem in other languages I go for a separation of code and HTML. Something like:

1.) Create a HTML template. use `[varname]` placeholders to mark replaced/inserted content.
2.) Fill your template variables from an array or structure/mapping/dictionary

```
Write( FillTemplate(myHTMLTemplate, myVariables) ) # pseudo-code
```

Comment: can i get a link to an example of how to make a HTML template? in whatever language? (i can deal with non C# is its .NET)

Comment: There are existing template engines that may help make this easier.  See wikipedia for a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)

Comment: The Parser class in here is simple/easy to use: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mailtemplates.aspx

Comment: @SpliFF - can you use the same [varname] more than once in the template for multiple places of the same information ?

Answer (score 17):

Use an `XDocument` to create the DOM, then write it out using an `XmlWriter`. This will give you a wonderfully concise and readable notation as well as nicely formatted output.

Take this sample program:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var xDocument = new XDocument(
            new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
            new XElement("html",
                new XElement("head"),
                new XElement("body",
                    new XElement("p",
                        "This paragraph contains ", new XElement("b", "bold"), " text."
                    ),
                    new XElement("p",
                        "This paragraph has just plain text."
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true, IndentChars = "\t"
        };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\wolf\Desktop\test.html", settings)) {
            xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <p>This paragraph contains <b>bold</b> text.</p>
        <p>This paragraph has just plain text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I love this option. Have you come across a way to add attributes inline with this format?

Comment: Sure! Just add an XAttribute within an XElement.

Comment: This is so much nicer than using `HtmlTextWriter`.

Comment: Can you add  some For loop when using this style?

Answer (score 14):

I know you asked about C#, but if you're willing to use any .Net language then I highly recommend Visual Basic for this exact problem.  Visual Basic has a feature called XML Literals that will allow you to write code like this.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim myTitle = "Hello HTML"
        Dim myHTML = <html>
                         <head>
                             <title><%= myTitle %></title>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                             <h1>Welcome</h1>
                             <table>
                                 <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
                                 <tr><td>1</td><td>CouldBeAVariable</td></tr>
                             </table>
                         </body>
                     </html>

        Console.WriteLine(myHTML)
    End Sub

End Module
```

This allows you to write straight HTML with expression holes in the old ASP style and makes your code super readable.  Unfortunately this feature is not in C#, but you could write a single module in VB and add it as a reference to your C# project.

Writing in Visual Studio also allows proper indentation for most XML Literals and expression wholes.  Indentation for the expression holes is better in VS2010.

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Good call.

Comment: This is a really awesome feature of VB. I created a gist that converts any DataTable into an HTML table tag in a generic manner: https://gist.github.com/sergkr/13d57dca75b385f0a359

Comment: Wish we had this in C# :(

Answer (score 7):

```
return string.Format(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""      ""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"">
<html>
<title>{0}</title>
<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""style.css"">
</head>
<body>
", title);
```

Comment: Depending on where title came from, you probably want to HTML-encode title before blindly inserting it into a string.

Comment: Back when I used such a clumsy method I would separate each line by adding an `Environment.NewLine` between html lines where I wanted to keep the breaks.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `System.Xml.Linq` objects. They were totally redesigned from the old `System.Xml` days which made constructing XML from scratch really annoying.

Other than the doctype I guess, you could easily do something like:

```
var html = new XElement("html",
    new XElement("head",
        new XElement("title", "My Page")
    ),
    new XElement("body",
        "this is some text"
    )
);
```

Comment: This is great, you can also use `new XElement("div", new XAttribute("class", "container"))` for creating attributes for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 5):

The most straight forward way is to use an XmlWriter object.  This can be used to produce valid HTML and will take care of all of the nasty escape sequences for you.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use **T4 Templates** for generating Html (or any) from your code.
see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

Comment: This is a really cool method. You would probably have gotten more votes if you had included more detail.

Comment: This. Note that T4 can be run both at compile time and at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ASP.NET to generate your HTML outside the context of web pages.  [Here's an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616111630/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122006-1.aspx) that shows how it can be done.

Comment: It could be used to generate an HTML email or something else that isn't a website.  Also, this isn't an answer.

Comment: You can use ASP.NET to output HTML outside the context of a web site.

Comment: I wouldnt go as far as downvoting this, as its a valid question, but it shoud have been a comment to the OP instead of an aswer

Comment: Jacob is correct... you can use the ASP.NET rendering engine... though there is obviously more to it than just saying you can use it.

Comment: i didnt up or down vote this but how would i use the rendering engine? link to a page of any example would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to create an HTML document similar to how you would create an XML document in C#, you could try Microsoft's open source library, the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

It provides an HtmlDocument object that has a very similar API to the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class.

Comment: Html Agility Pack was not written by Microsoft.

Comment: It probably wasn't officially sponsored by Microsoft, but at the very least it was written by a Microsoft employee, or at least someone with an @microsoft.com email address...

Comment: Yup, it was written by Simon Mourier who at that time was working at Microsoft... I wouldn't call it "Microsoft's open source library" though.

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of Razor in ASP.net MVC, the best way to write HTML in C# is with the Razor Engine.

```
string templatePath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\EmailTemplates"; 

IRazorLightEngine engine = EngineFactory.CreatePhysical(templatePath); 

var model = new Notification 
{ 
       Name = "Jone", 
       Title = "Test Email", 
       Content = "This is a test" 
}; 

string result = engine.Parse("template.cshtml", model);
```

Template:

```
<h2>Dear @Model.Name, you have a notification.</h2> 

<h1>@Model.Title</h1> 
<p>@Model.Content</p> 

<p>Date:@DateTime.Now</p>
```

For a complete sample, see [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-razor-engine-089934a6)

Comment: This is the right answer. Although i would recommend using the latest version of the package in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some third party open-source libraries to generated strong typed verified (X)HTML, such as [CityLizard Framework](http://citylizard.codeplex.com/) or Sharp DOM.

**Update** For example

```
html
    [head
        [title["Title of the page"]]
        [meta_(
            content: "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
            http_equiv: "Content-Type")
        ]
        [link_(href: "css/style.css", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css")]
        [script_(type: "text/javascript", src: "/JavaScript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")]
    ]
    [body
        [div
            [h1["Test Form to Test"]]
            [form_(action: "post", id: "Form1")
                [div
                    [label["Parameter"]]
                    [input_(type: "text", value: "Enter value")]
                    [input_(type: "submit", value: "Submit!")]
                ]
            ]
            [div
                [p["Textual description of the footer"]]
                [a_(href: "http://google.com/")
                    [span["You can find us here"]]
                ]
                [div["Another nested container"]]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a generic solution, however, if your pupose is to have or maintain email templates then System.Web has a built-in class called [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx). This class is used by the ASP.NET membership controls to create HTML emails.

Does the same kind of 'string replace' things as mentioned above, but packs it all into a MailMessage for you.

Here is an example from MSDN:

```
ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
replacements.Add("<%To%>",sourceTo.Text);
replacements.Add("<%From%>", md.From);
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage fileMsg;
fileMsg = md.CreateMailMessage(toAddresses, replacements, emailTemplate, this); 
return fileMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own classes with its Render method, and another attributes, to avoid a great mess if you use it a lot, and then use the HTMLWriter or the xmlwriter as well. 
This logic is used in the asp.net pages, you can inherit from webControl and override the [render method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.render.aspx), wich is great if you are developing server-side controls.
[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/customhtmlattributes.aspx) could be a good example.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are going for, and specifically, what kind of performance you really need to offer.

I've seen admirable solutions for strongly-typed HTML development (complete control models, be it ASP.NET Web Controls, or similar to it) that just add amazing complexity to a project. In other situations, it is perfect.

In order of preference in the C# world,

- ASP.NET Web Controls
- ASP.NET primitives and HTML controls
- XmlWriter and/or HtmlWriter
- If doing Silverlight development with HTML interoperability, consider something strongly typed like [link text](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/managed-html-controls-source/)
- StringBuilder and other super primitives

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these classes which served me well. It's simple yet pragmatic.

```
public class HtmlAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public HtmlAttribute(string name) : this(name, null) { }

    public HtmlAttribute(
        string name,
        string @value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = @value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Value))
            return this.Name;

        if (this.Value.Contains('"'))
            return string.Format("{0}='{1}'", this.Name, this.Value);

        return string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", this.Name, this.Value);
    }
}

public class HtmlElement
{
    protected List<HtmlAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    protected List<object> Childs { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    protected HtmlElement Parent { get; set; }

    public HtmlElement() : this(null) { }

    public HtmlElement(string name, params object[] childs)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Attributes = new List<HtmlAttribute>();
        this.Childs = new List<object>();

        if (childs != null && childs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in childs)
            {
                Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(object o)
    {
        var a = o as HtmlAttribute;
        if (a != null)
            this.Attributes.Add(a);
        else
        {
            var h = o as HtmlElement;
            if (h != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
            {
                h.Parent = this;
                this.Childs.Add(h);
            }
            else
                this.Childs.Add(o);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
        {
            result.Append(string.Format("<{0}", this.Name));
            if (this.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                result.Append(" ");
                foreach (var attr in this.Attributes)
                {
                    result.Append(attr.ToString());
                    result.Append(" ");
                }

                result = new StringBuilder(result.ToString().TrimEnd(' '));
            }

            if (this.Childs.Count == 0)
            {
                result.Append(" />");
            }
            else
            {
                result.AppendLine(">");

                foreach (var c in this.Childs)
                {
                    var cParts = c.ToString().Split('\n');

                    foreach (var p in cParts)
                    {
                        result.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", p));
                    }
                }

                result.Append(string.Format("</{0}>", this.Name));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var c in this.Childs)
            {
                var cParts = c.ToString().Split('\n');

                foreach (var p in cParts)
                {
                    result.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", p));
                }
            }
        }

        var head = GetHeading(this);

        var ps = result.ToString().Split('\n');
        return string.Join("\r\n", (from p in ps select head + p.TrimEnd('\r')).ToArray());
    }

    string GetHeading(HtmlElement h)
    {
        if (h.Parent != null)
            return "    ";
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HSharp is a library used to analyse markup language like HTML easily and fastly.
Install: `PM> Install-Package Obisoft.HSharp`

```
        var Document = new HDoc(DocumentOptions.BasicHTML);
        Document["html"]["body"].AddChild("div");
        Document["html"]["body"]["div"].AddChild("a", new HProp("href", "/#"));
        Document["html"]["body"]["div"].AddChild("table");
        Document["html"]["body"]["div"]["table"].AddChildren(
         new HTag("tr"),
         new HTag("tr", "SomeText"),
         new HTag("tr", new HTag("td")));
        var Result = Document.GenerateHTML();
        Console.WriteLine(Result);
```

and output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta><title>
Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="/#"></a><table>
<tr></tr><tr>
SomeText </tr>
<tr>
<td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something that looked like jquery for generating dom in C# (I don't need to parse). Unfortunately no luck in finding a lightweight solution so I created this simple class that is inherited from System.Xml.Linq.XElement. The key feature is that you can chain the operator like when using jquery in javascript so it's more fluent. It's not fully featured but it does what I need and if there is interest I can start a git.

```
public class DomElement : XElement
{
    public DomElement(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public DomElement(string name, string value) : base(name, value)
    {
    }

    public DomElement Css(string style, string value)
    {
        style = style.Trim();
        value = value.Trim();
        var existingStyles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var xstyle = this.Attribute("style");
        if (xstyle != null)
        {
            foreach (var s in xstyle.Value.Split(';'))
            {
                var keyValue = s.Split(':');
                existingStyles.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue.Length < 2 ? null : keyValue[1]);
            }
        }

        if (existingStyles.ContainsKey(style))
        {
            existingStyles[style] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            existingStyles.Add(style, value);
        }

        var styleString = string.Join(";", existingStyles.Select(s => $"{s.Key}:{s.Value}"));
        this.SetAttributeValue("style", styleString);

        return this;
    }

    public DomElement AddClass(string cssClass)
    {
        var existingClasses = new List<string>();
        var xclass = this.Attribute("class");
        if (xclass != null)
        {
            existingClasses.AddRange(xclass.Value.Split());
        }

        var addNewClasses = cssClass.Split().Where(e => !existingClasses.Contains(e));
        existingClasses.AddRange(addNewClasses);

        this.SetAttributeValue("class", string.Join(" ", existingClasses));
        return this;
    }

    public DomElement Text(string text)
    {
        this.Value = text;
        return this;
    }

    public DomElement Append(string text)
    {
        this.Add(text);
        return this;
    }

    public DomElement Append(DomElement child)
    {
        this.Add(child);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var html = new DomElement("html")
        .Append(new DomElement("head"))
        .Append(new DomElement("body")
            .Append(new DomElement("p")
                .Append("This paragraph contains")
                .Append(new DomElement("b", "bold"))
                .Append(" text.")
                )
            .Append(new DomElement("p").Text("This paragraph has just plain text"))
            )
        ;

    html.ToString().Dump();

    var table = new DomElement("table").AddClass("table table-sm").AddClass("table-striped")
            .Append(new DomElement("thead")
                .Append(new DomElement("tr")
                    .Append(new DomElement("td").Css("padding-left", "15px").Css("color", "red").Css("color", "blue")
                        .AddClass("from-now")
                        .Append(new DomElement("div").Text("Hi there"))
                        .Append(new DomElement("div").Text("Hey there"))
                        .Append(new DomElement("div", "Yo there"))
                        )
                )
            )
        ;
    table.ToString().Dump();
}
```

output from above code:

```
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    <p>This paragraph contains<b>bold</b> text.</p>
    <p>This paragraph has just plain text</p>
  </body>
</html>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:15px;color:blue" class="from-now">
        <div>Hi there</div>
        <div>Hey there</div>
        <div>Yo there</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```