# How to create an HTML file using C# desktop application

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I want to create an HTML file from the database records..

I Am working on a desktop application. How can I create such a file?

I tried on the internet and fount that `XMLwriter` can be used.

But I have no experience in `XMLWRITER`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004776/write-html-in-c-sharp

Comment: I could help you by recommending you read the MSDN lib at XMLWriter.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx Also someone has produced some example code on how to use it. Have you done any research at all?  If so what problems are you having?