# How to add html tags using C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

I have the following HTML script

```
<h1>
 This is heading one
</h1>
<p>
 This is paragraph.
</p>
```

Now I want to seek your kind suggestions to add `<html></html>` in the above script using C#.

Comment: Are you using asp.net?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004776/write-html-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you have the HTML in a text file that you want to edit using C#, or is this just held in a `string`? Can you show us what you've tried and the specific problem you've encountered?

Comment: You should include (more) code.

Comment: This question may attracts lot of negative points, because you are not specifying the exact issue or requirement. Paste some code and reply to the comments may help SO users to contribute more solutions. Also this is a simple thing may be goggling can help you to figure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
 string script = @"< h1>
                            This is heading one
                            < /h1>
                            < p>
                             This is paragraph.
                            < /p>";
        string sciptAfter = "<html>" + script + "</html>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a StringBuilder to achieve this also:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Append("<html>");
stringBuilder.AppendLine(<yourString>);
stringBuilder.AppendLine("</html>");
//to get the html use
var formatedHtml = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Hope this helps,

Mishu

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "your html code";
text = "<html>" + Environment.NewLine + text + Environment.Newline + "</html>";
```