# How to send colorful mail in nlog

Tags: c#, html-email, nlog

below config was my nlog setting, this setting send mail is OK .

```
<target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"
            smtpServer="SMTP SERVER"
            smtpPort="25"
            smtpAuthentication="None"   
            enableSsl="false"   
            from="email address"  
            to="email address"
            html="true"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            addNewLines="true"
            replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml ="true"
            subject="SYSTEM MESSAGE：${machinename} 於 ${shortdate} ${time} create ${level} message "
            header="========================================================================="
            body="${newline} 
            time：${longdate} ${newline}${newline}
            Log level：${level:uppercase=true} ${newline}${newline}
            Logger：${logger} ${newline}${newline}
            Source：${callsite:className=true} ${newline}${newline}
            Exception：${exception:format=type} ${newline}${newline}
            Error message：${message} ${newline}${newline}"     
            footer="========================================================================="
    />

</targets>

 <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
 </rules>
```

but I want to send colorful mail. How to setting configure ?

Comment: I was looking for a way to HTMLise my body of NLog Mail Target. Then I came at this. Your formatting looks awesome to me for now so I am using this for a while. Thanks bruh.

Answer (score 3):

For markup like colors in your e-mail, you need a html mail and CSS styling.

e.g. this html:

```html
<body>
    <b style="color:red">Bold and red text</b>
</body>
```

You need to set the `html` option on the mail target to `true` and in your nlog.config you need to XML encode the html, so in result:

```xml
<target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"
            html="true"
            ...

            body="&lt;body&gt;
&lt;b style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;Bold and red text&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;"
    />
```

Please note that not all CSS is supported in all email clients. See [CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score -1):

An easy approach is to log messages with the HTML already in the logged string, for example:

In the config file:

```
<targets>
   <target 
      name="mail" 
      xsi:type="Mail" 
      replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml="true"
      html="true"
      body="${message}"             
   />
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="mail"></logger>
</rules>
```

In the code:

```
log.Info("<strong>My Bolded Message</string>");
```

Also, instead of inlining the HTML tags, one can use an HTML library like [htmltags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170337/269582) or even [System.Xml.Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1004892/3002584) to make it much more robust.

Comment: This approach is problematic if you have different log targets. You'll pollute all your other logs with HTML-Markup.